# Atmel Button Debounce not working

Tags: c, atmel

I am trying to make a button debounce software by the help of an led toggle function that returns a different boolean each time which i got by asking the question before but that never worked :

```
#include <avr/io.h>

bool ledToggle();

int main(void)
{   
    DDRB |= (1 << 0); 
    DDRB &= ~(1 << 0); 

    while(1)
    {   
        //TODO:: Please write your application code                 

        if (ledToggle() == true)
        {       
            //led on
            PORTB |= (1 << 0);          
        }else{          
            //led off
            PORTB &= ~(1 << 0);         
        }       
    }
}

bool ledToggle()
{
    static bool state = false;  
    if(bit_is_clear(PINB, 1)){
        state = !state;
    }

    return state;   
}
```

---

***EDIT***

I get no errors or anything when I try to compile it just doesn't work...

Comment: Are you getting any errors, getting unexpected output? Are you stuck?Can you form a clear question please?

Comment: no @TimCastelijns. I get nothing. it just doesn't work

Comment: What do you expect it to do ? What does it do ? Explain better your problem, please.

Comment: the led just keeps off whatever I try to do and never turns on

Comment: @blue112 it is a button debounce software it is supposed to turn on the led when I press the button and turn it off when I press it again

Answer (score 0):

In the second line of main () you are mistakenly setting the LED port instead of the BUTTON port as an input.

I suggest using defines as a way of making this kind of mistakes less likely:

```
#define LED    0
#define BUTTON 1

DDRB |= (1 << LED);
DDRB &= ~(1 << BUTTON);
```

Comment: Needs explanation of why / what the change actually does to be a quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize in which way this code would debounce a switch connected to Port B / 1. Debouncing means to

- check and store the key logic state
- wait a certain amount of time (depending on hardware, 5 - 50 ms)
- compare the (now) logic state with what was read before
- if equal the (now) logic state is the debounced key state

Provided the program is functioning well, the LED would bounce at the same pace as the switch.

In your `bool ledToggle()` I suggest you declare `static volatile bool state;` to ensure the variable is created in RAM (rather than a CPU register)